# Running Excel's OFFSET using WorkSheetFunction causes error 438

Tags: vba, excel

My main goal is to create a named range that automatically resizes.

A common way to do this is to use the `OFFSET` formula in Excel and dynamically determine the height and/or width parameter values using `CountA`. I would like to do this using VBA. For simplicity purposes, I took a step back and focused just on getting `OFFSET` to run and return a range. I have the following code:

```
Public Function testfn()
   Dim r As Range
   On Error Resume Next
   Set r = WorksheetFunction.Offset(Worksheets("MAIN").Range("H85"), 0, 0, 1, 2)
   Debug.Print Err.Number
 End Function
```

The output in the console is `438`. I'm not really sure what's causing it because I have specified the starting reference explicitly and the rest of the values are hard-coded integers.

Can you please point out what exactly is causing the error? Could it be that it's not actually possible to call this function using VBA?

Comment: There is no `WorksheetFunction.Offset`.

Comment: look for `Range.Offset`

Comment: To be clear there is an Excel function called `OFFSET` that can be used be directly in cell editing. However, this function is not exposed as a member in the vba `WorksheetFunction` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error 438 stands for: **Object doesn't support this property or method.** 
(It might be worth to comment out the `On Error Resume Next` when you are debugging in order to have this information.)

This means that the method `Offset` is not supported by the object `WorksheetFunction`. This can be a little surprising since it does not appear on the list of functions that are not available in VBA according to Microsoft ([See list](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/213660/not-all-excel-worksheet-functions-are-supported-as-methods-of-the-appl)).

However, it is indeed not available since it's not part of the methods listed here:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822194(v=office.14).aspx (Office 2010)
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-object-excel (Office 365)

**Alternatives:**
As already suggested by Tim Williams, using the `Resize` method of the `Range` Object is the easiest way to do what you are trying to do, but if you prefer to use the `Offset` method, you could use:

```
   Dim r As Range, s As Range
   Set s = Worksheets("MAIN").Range("H85")
   Set r = Range(s, s.Offset(0, 1))
```

or alternatively, you can use the `Evaluate` function like this:

```
Set r = Application.Evaluate("Offset('MAIN'!H5, 0, 0, 1, 2)")
```

But this one would be a little bit slower.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's input! I chose the answer above as the best answer because it is very detailed and provides not only alternatives to how to solve the problem, but also gives references to verify that VBA doesn't support Excel's OFFSET.

Answer (score 5):

To mimic `=OFFSET(rng, offR, offC, sizeR, sizeC)` you can use either or both of:

```
rng.Offset(offR, offC)
```

and

```
rng.Resize(sizeR, sizeC)
```

or combined:

```
    rng.Offset(offR, offC).Resize(sizeR, sizeC)
```

Since you're not actually offsetting here, you only need:

```
Set r = Worksheets("MAIN").Range("H85").Resize(1, 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
Set r = Worksheets("MAIN").Range("H85").Resize(1, 2)
```

Comment: `Resize`, not `Offset`